# Using a nested loop to create a nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

The larger scope of what I am trying to accomplish is this.  I have a `Windows directory` that can contain a variable number of `.csv` files.  These files were generated as test results from a PLC.  They are differentiated by their filenames.  Every cycle the test generates 2 `.csv` files.  The first file name contains an order number, a `-` delimiter, and the string `UP`.  The second file is identical except the string is replaced with `DOWN`.

Example file name:
`1234567890-UP` or `1234567890-DOWN`

Example of directory:
`1234567890-UP.csv`
`1234567890-DOWN.csv`
`2000005001-UP.csv`
`2000005001-DOWN.csv`

I am trying to write a script that loops through all the file names in the directory and stores them in a list.  Then removes everything except the order number from the elements.  Then removes duplicate elements. Using the example directory above I would have a list that looks like `[1234567890,2000005001]`.  I have accomplished this much.
Now what I am trying to do is loop through the original list of filenames and compare them against my new list to create a nested list which separates the files based of their order numbers.  Using the same example directory the list would look like this: `[[1234567890-UP.csv,1234567890-DOWN.csv],[2000005001-UP.csv,2000005001-DOWN.csv]]`
Finally I want to loop through this list and merge the `.csv` files together based off list index.

There might be an easier way to do this that I overlooked that would save me a lot of trouble.

My current code to fill the nested list using a nested for loop looks like this

```
    nestedlist=[]
    for x in range(len(filenamelist)):
        for y in range(len(filteredlist)):
            if filteredlist[y] in filenamelist[x]:
                nestedlist[y].append(filenamelist[x]
```

This returns an error `Index out of range`.  This makes since because the size of `nestedlist` was never defined.  I'm not really sure how to do that or what the best way to do that is?

Comment: so you want to iterate over the initial list and create a new nested list which is paired??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved in a much simpler way. Suppose you have the list of files of the directory as -

```
files = [1234567890-UP.csv,1234567890-DOWN.csv,2000005001-UP.csv,2000005001-DOWN.csv]
```

You could iterate over this, create a map of order number to the actual filenames.

```
filemap = {}
for file in files:
  order_number = re.compile('(\d*)-(\w*).csv').match(file).groups()[0]
  print(order_number)
  files = filemap.get(order_number, [])
  files.append(file)
  filemap[order_number] = files
```

That should give something like this.

```
{'1234567890': ['1234567890-UP.csv', '1234567890-DOWN.csv'],
 '2000005001': ['2000005001-UP.csv', '2000005001-DOWN.csv']}
```

Now you can lookup on the order number and merge when required

Comment: This solved my problem.  Also gave me the opportunity to learn about regular expressions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should append straight to `nestedlist`, not to `nestedlist[y]`. There's no index `y` in an empty list.

You could also simplify this way; the `range` is unnecessary since you can just loop over the list directly:

```
nestedlist=[]
   for x in filenamelist:
      for y in filteredlist:
         if y in x:
            nestedlist.append(x)
```